# Going to buy this theme. But w3 validator says it's invalid

Tags: html, wordpress-theming, w3c-validation

I was going to buy this wordpress theme.

http://progressionstudios.com/themes-wp/?theme=Renovation

But when I checked it through validator.w3.org , it says the page is Invalid.

It says 5 Errors, 36 warnings

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fprogressionstudios.com%2Fthemes-wp%2F%3Ftheme%3DRenovation&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Well, my question is, does it really matter ?  Should I really care about these 5 Errors, 36 warnings and avoid buying this theme ? Or forget the errors and go ahead. ?

Comment: You don't even include the errors. How should we know if they matter to you?

Comment: This is primarily opinion-based. Read the warnings/errors and evaluate, for yourself, if you can live with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You checked the site which is embeding the theme for errors not the theme itself. Click the remove this frame button on the top right and you will get the original adress of this theme.

The Theme:

http://renovation.progressionstudios.com/

The Validation:

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Frenovation.progressionstudios.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3+http%3A%2F%2Fvalidator.w3.org%2Fservices

8 Errors & 1 Warning

Doesnt look so bad i think - you could just fix these by yourself the validator even tells you how.

Comment: Just test the theme on every browser and look if it's working as expected. The errors from the validator are not a very good indication for a good website, even Facebook got errors on the validation test.